# Connecting to mysql on another server.

Tags: php, mysqli

The solutions I got are not working for me. Here is my code -

```
//Connect to database
$tempCon = new mysqli($domain, $username, $password, $database);
if ($tempCon->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL Database: (" . $tempCon->connect_errno . ") " . $tempCon->connect_error;
} else {
    echo "connected";
}
```

The error I am getting is -

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'domain.info' (110) in /home/server/public_html/products/websites/EditWebsiteContent.php on line 8
Failed to connect to MySQL Database: (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'doamin.info' (110)
```

Comment: Firewalls usually do not allow access of port 3306, which is the network port of MySQL. Check network connection by `telnet`.

Comment: so if it is not allowed then what to do with it?

Comment: Your server IP must be added to mysql remote access allowed hosts on remote host in order to access. If its already added then as Raptor said it might be firewall

Comment: By exposing port 3306 to public, your MySQL database will be vulnerable to attacks. Use VPN if needed. Best practice is to load database in same private network or even better, the same machine

Comment: The problem is the mysql db i want to connect is different for different requests. So adding the ip would not be feasible for this (i think).

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the firewalls on the server which doesnot allow to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared hosting. You need to allow remote connecting to your database from your IP address.